# Include graphics under enumeration, align top with number?

Tags: graphics, enumerate, includegraphics

Currently the bottom of the image is aligned with the enumeration number, how can I align the top of the image instead?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item %1
    \includegraphics{test.png}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[Export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item %1
    \includegraphics[width=5cm,valign=t]{example-image.png}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @David Carlisle --- This answer is different from the answers to the duplicate question, and arguably better. Perhaps you could also post it as an answer there (or maybe there is some site convention for moving answers in such cases).

Comment: @IanThompson I looked when it was marked as dup, but it's essentially the same as egreg's accepted answer ther, adjustbox/valign=t isn't it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --- My mistake; I didn't see that your answer requires the adjustbox package.